# ApexCharts RangeArea Customization

Tags: reactjs, graph, visualization, apexcharts

I'm trying to create a range area chart using ApexCharts where there are two lines with different colors, but the filled area between them should have the same color as the first line. I have provided my current chart configuration below:

```
  const chartState = {
    series: [
      {
        name: "San Diego",
        data: [2.5, 2.8, 3.0, 2.5, 2.8, 3.0],
      },
      {
        name: "National",
        data: [2, 1.2, 2.8, 2, 1.2, 2.8],
      },
    ],
    options: {
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "area",
      },
      colors: ["#FFC700", "#7000FF"],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      stroke: {
        curve: "straight",
      },
      fill: {
        type: "gradient",
        gradient: {
          shadeIntensity: 1,
          opacityFrom: 0.7,
          opacityTo: 0.9,
          stops: [0, 100],
        },
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: "datetime",
        categories: [
          "2022-08-30T00:00:00.000Z",
          "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z",
          "2022-10-30T00:00:00.000Z",
          "2022-11-30T00:00:00.000Z",
          "2022-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
          "2023-01-30T00:00:00.000Z",
        ],
      },
      yaxis: {
        min: 0.5,
        max: 3.0,
      },
      tooltip: {
        x: {
          format: "dd/MM/yy",
        },
      },
      legend: {
        position: "top",
        horizontalAlign: "right",
      },
      annotations: {
        xaxis: [
          {
            x: "2022-10-30T00:00:00.000Z",
            fillColor: "#B3F7CA",
            opacity: 0.4,
          },
          {
            x: "2022-11-30T00:00:00.000Z",
            fillColor: "#B3F7CA",
            opacity: 0.4,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  };
```

The chart currently looks like this:
[image]

However, I want the chart to look like this:
[image]

In the desired chart, you can see that both lines have different colors, but the area between the lines has the same color as the first line. How can I achieve this result in ApexCharts?

Answer (score 0):

You may add another line series for the lower bound on top of the range-area to achieve the desired result.

```js
var options = {
  series: [
    {
      name: "New York Temperature",
      type: "rangeArea",
      data: [
        {
          x: "Jan 2021",
          y: [-2, 4]
        },
        {
          x: "Feb 2021",
          y: [-1, 6]
        },
        {
          x: "Mar 2021",
          y: [3, 10]
        },
        {
          x: "Apr 2021",
          y: [8, 16]
        },
        {
          x: "May 2021",
          y: [13, 22]
        },
        {
          x: "Jun 2021",
          y: [18, 26]
        },
        {
          x: "Jul 2021",
          y: [21, 29]
        },
        {
          x: "Aug 2021",
          y: [21, 28]
        },
        {
          x: "Sep 2021",
          y: [17, 24]
        },
        {
          x: "Oct 2021",
          y: [11, 18]
        },
        {
          x: "Nov 2021",
          y: [6, 12]
        },
        {
          x: "Dec 2021",
          y: [1, 7]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "New York Temperature",
      type: "line",
      data: [
        {
          x: "Jan 2021",
          y: -2
        },
        {
          x: "Feb 2021",
          y: -1
        },
        {
          x: "Mar 2021",
          y: 3
        },
        {
          x: "Apr 2021",
          y: 8
        },
        {
          x: "May 2021",
          y: 13
        },
        {
          x: "Jun 2021",
          y: 18
        },
        {
          x: "Jul 2021",
          y: 21
        },
        {
          x: "Aug 2021",
          y: 21
        },
        {
          x: "Sep 2021",
          y: 17
        },
        {
          x: "Oct 2021",
          y: 11
        },
        {
          x: "Nov 2021",
          y: 6
        },
        {
          x: "Dec 2021",
          y: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: "rangeArea",
    animations: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  stroke: {
    curve: "straight",
    width: 2
  },
  markers: {
    hover: {
      sizeOffset: 5
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: (val) => {
        return val + "°C";
      }
    }
  },
  fill: {
    opacity: [0.1, 1]
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: "datetime"
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```css
#chart {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 35px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@3.37.3/dist/apexcharts.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart">
</div>
```